# Templates Doesnot exist at /accounts/login

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using django-registraion for authentication of users. I did install django-registration via pip and added in the settings.py file. However it is still giving me the Templtate doesnot exist error. Here's the error:

```
 TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
 registration/login.html
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/
 Django Version:    1.11.3
 Exception Type:    TemplateDoesNotExist
 Exception Value:   registration/login.html
 Exception Location:    C:\Python34\lib\site-     packages\django\template\loader.py in select_template, line 53
```

Here's the code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from chat.views import index
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',index, name='homepage'),  # The start point for index view
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login, name='login'),  # The base django login view
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', logout, name='logout'),  # The base django logout view
```

in the settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
    'registration',
]
```

[This is the structure of my django project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk4qj.png)

Comment: In settings.py, you need to add template path.

Answer (score 2):

it seems the templates folder is at the root directory, so you need to change your settings to this

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR + '/templates/',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list of context processors

            ],
            'debug': True
        },
    },
]
```